# MikTex.Sorry, but latex did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

Tags: miktex

when i have installed Miktex and update, i type "latex -v" in cmd and found error:

```
Sorry, but latex did not succeed.The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:C:\Users\10950\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\latex.log
```

and in my latex.log i found this:

```
2021-12-15 17:23:14,228+0800 INFO  latex - this process (38868) started by 'cmd' with command line: latex -v
2021-12-15 17:23:14,232+0800 INFO  latex - this is MiKTeX-PDFTEX 4.10.0 (1.40.24) (MiKTeX 21.12.10)
2021-12-15 17:23:14,236+0800 INFO  latex - allowing known shell commands
2021-12-15 17:23:14,260+0800 FATAL latex.core - The command line options could not be processed.
2021-12-15 17:23:14,260+0800 FATAL latex.core - Data: optionError="unknown option"
2021-12-15 17:23:14,260+0800 FATAL latex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\webapp.cpp:397
2021-12-15 17:23:14,260+0800 FATAL latex - The command line options could not be processed.
2021-12-15 17:23:14,260+0800 FATAL latex - Info: optionError="unknown option"
2021-12-15 17:23:14,260+0800 FATAL latex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\webapp.cpp
2021-12-15 17:23:14,260+0800 FATAL latex - Line: 397
2021-12-15 17:23:14,263+0800 INFO  latex - this process (38868) finishes with exit code 1
```

how to fix this ,thanks